# fantasy - sci fi novel about a cripple

Tags: story-identification, books

Details I remember:

- There is a video game where he is a powerful thief or warrior
- He wasn't always a cripple
- There is some sort of Corporation he is fighting against as well

Comment: Do you have any more details? Anything about the plot? Details about the characters? What language/nationality was the novel? How old is it/when did you read it?

Comment: I know not everybody has English as a first language, and probably no offense was intended, but "a cripple" is generally not a super awesome way to describe somebody with a disability.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like Matthew Stover's *Acts of Caine* series, specifically the second volume, [*Blade of Tyshalle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_of_Tyshalle). The hero was a powerful warrior in an alternate fantasy world whose adventurers are televised on Earth (rather than a video game), is now paraplegic, and is struggling against the company he works for.

Answer (score 3):

Without more details, it also sounds somewhat like Otherland series by Tad Williams.  I am a bit fuzzy on details too sorry.  A young boy named Orlando has a debilitating disease and loses all movement etc. There is an evil corporation, Grail Brotherhood, that he and others are fighting against within the game and other people are fighting outside of the game.  The game itself is sort of like the Matrix, people can plug into the Otherland and actually become their characters, any sort of character they desire.  In the game he creates an LotR style character named Thargor.