# Fantasy novel series with paraplegic protagonist who travels back and forth between Earth and his world

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

I am looking for a fantasy book where the main character travels back and forth between Earth and his world and they watch him like he is on TV.

He gets stabbed in the stomach and in the second book becomes a paraplegic and gets use of his spine back.

Comment: http://science4fiction4fantasy.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/book-series-about-paraplegic.html

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/The-Guardians-Flame-Joel-Rosenberg/dp/0743435893?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18005661-the-four-treasures-of-eirean?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56529/fantasy-sci-fi-novel-about-a-cripple

Answer (score 6):

*[Blade of Tyshalle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_of_Tyshalle)*, sequel to *[Heroes Die](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_Die)*, both by Matthew Stover.

### *Heroes Die*

[image: Heroes Die cover]

> The novels are set in a future dystopia Earth where a parallel world called Overworld reminiscent of the worlds featured in post-Tolkien secondary world fantasy has been discovered. The corporations that run Earth send actors into Overworld in order to provide the masses of an overcrowded world with virtual-reality entertainment.

### *Blade of Tyshalle*

[image: Blade of Tyshalle cover]

> Seven years after the events of *Heroes Die*, Hari Michaelson (also known as Caine) is a puppet executive on the Studio he used to work for. He is now a paraplegic and lives with his wife Shanna and her daughter Faith.